# ASP.NET api getting null as request body

Tags: c#, .net, angular, api

I have my controller class as

```
namespace air_bnb.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserDbContext context;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public UserController(IConfiguration configuration, UserDbContext _context)
        { 
            _config = configuration;
            context = _context;
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(LoginReqDto request)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(request.Password);
            var hashedPw = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(request.Password);
            User createdUser = new User
                                   {
                                       Email = request.Email,
                                       Password = hashedPw,
                                       Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                                   };

            createdUser.Email = request.Email;
            createdUser.Password = hashedPw;

            await context.Users.AddAsync(createdUser);

            try 
            {
                await context.SaveChangesAsync(); 
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                return BadRequest(request.Password); 
            }

            return Ok(request.Password);
        }
    }
}
```

From the frontend, I am using `HTTPClient` in Angular. When I use Postman to send my data, everything works perfectly.

Comment: Well - then please **show us** how you make that call from Angular - and what data you're trying to pass

Comment: Added angular tag as this question relates to Angular. While please provide the info for how you submit the request through Angular, does the request submitted (Check the DevTools, network tab), as mentioned by marc.

Comment: I think you missed [ApiController] on controller class name. Like this 
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any difference in the body data are you sending from the Angular app and Postman? Like using form data(application/x-www-form-urlencoded) or JSON(application/json).

Here, you are using a `Controller` base class that default binds data from the from data. If you are passing data in the JSON format then you have to explicitly specify the [FromBody] attribute for the action parameter.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] LoginReqDto request)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I will look more into the Controller Base class.